# looking for a solution for generating pdf with client side (angular js)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, pdf, jspdf

I am looking for a solution to generate pdf from (html + css + javascript) using AngularJs.

I tested two solutions:

- jsPDF (it does not take the css)
- Shrimp (based on Ruby)

which do not work for me.

How can I do it?

Comment: have a look at the pdf.js project on github.

Comment: After all this, I discovered the excellent PhantomJS product.  The binary was easily installed on the server with no additional dependencies required, and came with a great deal of example code, including a working ‘print to PDF’ function out-of-the-box.  With some minor tweaks, we customized the script for our use case, and had a PDF copy of our webpages in minutes.  PhantomJS has been around since 2011 and is used by a variety of open source products, listed on their website

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After all this, I discovered the excellent [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org).

The binary was easily installed on the server with no additional dependencies required, and came with a great deal of example code, including a working ‘print to PDF’ function out-of-the-box. With some minor tweaks, we customized the script for our use case, and had a PDF copy of our webpages in minutes. PhantomJS has been around since 2011 and is used by a variety of open source products, listed on their websit

Comment: Isnt that a server side solution? In your question it looks like you were looking for a client side pdf creator

Comment: Yes, i look for server side solution :)